# Output a list of events along with timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in my PHPMyAdmin

1. brand
2. item
3. model

I am developing a PHP website that can be used to stock management. So basically the user can use it to input an item and display it along with the price and quantity.

So take an example, today I add in an item with

1. brand : A
2. model: B
3. quantity: 5
4. price : 123

and tomorrow I lessen the quantity by 1

and again in the other day I lessen the quantity by 1

And what I want is how to create a page that can be used to display all the events along with the time stamp??

it would be like this :

2014-09-19 brand A quantity -1

2014-09-20 brand A quantity -1

2014-09-21 brand A quantity -1

I already put the date into the model table, but it can only give the timestamp from the last event occurred

can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to create a separate table to record the transactions and timestamps.

Comment: do you mind to help me by providing an example? thanks :)

Comment: Make a new table called "transactions" and each time the stock goes down insert a record in the new table with the item id, the quantity change and the timestamp. Then when you pull up your item data you can join the 2 tables using the item id. Of course this assumes that you have an id for each item, which you should.